# MSP430G2553 keeps SCL and SDA low

Tags: embedded, sensors, i2c, msp430

I am working with a BMP180 using I2C but it's not working.
My I2C settings are these

```
void inicializarI2C() {
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;
    UCB0CTL0 &= ~(UCA10 | UCSLA10 | UCMM);
    UCB0CTL0 |= (UCMST | UCMODE1 | UCMODE0 | UCSYNC);
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCSSEL1 | UCSSEL0;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0STAT = 0;
    UCB0BR0 = 80;
    UCB0BR1 = 0;
    UCB0I2COA = 0x1A;
    UCB0I2CSA = 0xEE;
    P1SEL |= BIT6;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT6;
    P1SEL |= BIT7;
    P1SEL2 |= BIT7;
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
}
```

I start an I2C communication with this

```
void inicioI2C(uint8_t dir) {
    //UCB0I2CSA = dir;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT;
    UCB0TXBUF = 5;
    while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT) != 0) {
        if((UCB0STAT & UCNACKIFG) != 0) {
            UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;
            while((UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP) != 0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main function

```
int main(void)
{
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;   // stop watchdog timer
    P1DIR |= 0x01;
    P1OUT &= ~BIT0;
    conf_reloj(8);
    /*for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        P1OUT ^= 0x01;
        retardo_ms(1000);
    }*/
    inicializar_UART();
    inicializarI2C();

    while(1) {
        inicioI2C(0xEE);
        retardo_ms(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I already checked SCL and SDA signals and they stay low all the time. I think I2C communication is not even starting. NACK flag doesn't activate even tough apparently the sensor it's not responding.

Comment: Did you initialize the GPIO and/or verified that you can assert them ? Otherwise verify that your register values are in accordance with the datasheet.

Comment: @Sorenp It was the SCL pin that was connected to a resistance in my board. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The pull up i suppose ?

Comment: @Sorenp No, there was an extra resistance besides the pull up one. It was connected to a LED. I forgot to remove the jumper that joined the pin with that resistance.